# How is the history.el file written? Why did this change happen?

Tags: magit, git, history

I have been tweaking my config file (`init.el`). This file is inside a `.emacs.d` directory which is under version control by Git. I also use Magit a lot.

After editing my config, I was going to stage, commit, and push the changes. However, I have been surprised by Magit indicating changes on `.emacs.d/transient/history.el`. I **do not** understand how/why this file has been written the way it was.

For instance, this is what `git diff` inside the Magit interface is indicating about this file:

```lisp
1 file changed, 3 insertions(+), 4 deletions(-)
.emacs.d/transient/history.el | 7 +++----

modified   .emacs.d/transient/history.el
@@ -17,10 +17,9 @@
  (magit-log:--grep " 79504ca")
  (magit-pull nil
              ("--rebase"))
- (magit-push
-  ("--force-with-lease")
-  nil
-  ("--force"))
+ (magit-push nil
+             ("--force-with-lease")
+             ("--force"))
  (magit-rebase
   ("--autostash")
   nil)
```

Apparently, the change is a transposition of the `nil` expression with `("--force-with-lease")`. Why is this happening? What could have triggered this change? What is the relevance in the order?

Thanks

Comment: `transient` is a dependency of `magit`. In short, add it to `.gitignore` and don't try to make too much sense of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like `transient` save its history to `transient/history.el`. I don't think you need to care too much about how it's stored. I suggest you use [no-littering](https://github.com/emacscollective/no-littering) and add `no-littering-var-directory` into `.gitignore`.

Comment: How to add `no-filtering` if I have already been using a config file and there is already a `.emacs.d` directory?

Comment: @PedroDelfino Sorry, I don't really get your question. If you don't want to lose the original files, you can move them to the new directories set by `no-filtering`, default `etc` and `var`.