# Make Magit ignore certain files already added to git and to .gitignore

Tags: magit, git, version-control

This question is related to this [previous question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/71432/how-is-the-history-el-file-written-why-did-this-change-happen).

These two files below are under version control which causes some inconvenience in `magit-status`:

```lisp
Unstaged changes (2)
modified   .emacs.d/projectile-bookmarks.eld
modified   .emacs.d/transient/history.el
```

This is my `.gitignore` file:

```
transient
projectile-bookmarks.eld
.emacs.d/projectile-bookmarks.eld
.emacs.d/transient/history.el
```

The file location is: `.dotfiles/.gitignore`. I thought my `gitignore`file would solve this.

Did I miss something? How can I fix this?

I want to remove these files from being under version control. It is necessary to keep them in my machine, apparently - since the emacs package depends on it to properly work.

Comment: This is not a magit issue but a git issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45400361/why-is-gitignore-not-ignoring-my-files.  I dont know if any of the answers there is upto the mark. I recommend https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do here. You have files under version control, but you want them to be hidden when listing unstaged changes? I doubt Magit has this functionality. It would be confusing to not see unstaged changes if all the changed files are hidden, but those unstaged files would still prevent operations like rebasing that require a clean working directory.

Comment: Or do you want those files not to be under version control? If so, you need to remove them. `.gitignore` only prevents files from being added when adding a directory, or listed as unchanged when they aren't committed. It has no effect on files that are already committed.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil', thanks for trying to help! I want to remove these files from being under version control. It is necessary to keep them in my machine, apparently - since the emacs package depends on it to properly work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) is only relevant for files that are not already tracked by Git. If you've started tracking a file and now regret it, you need to remove it from Git. Once that's done, if the file is listed in `.gitignore`, Git will no longer propose to add it (but you can still add it by explicit request).

To remove a file from Git without removing it from your working directory, you can use [`magit-file-untrack`](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Commands-for-Buffers-Visiting-Files.html#index-magit_002dfile_002duntrack) (`K` from the Magit buffer). Then commit the change that removes the file.

Comment: This solved the problem, thank you!